# Print command writing in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, command

I am learning Python and have a question about the print command.

Why in the following case the code with print command works in one line:

```
text = "The vegetables are in the fridge."
print(text.replace("vegetables", "fruits"))
```

but here when I write like this, I get no result ?

```
numbers = [12, 34, 23, 88, 1, 65]
fruits = ["apple", "pear", "orange", "grapes", "mango"]
print(fruits.extend(numbers))
```

Correct way is the following:

```
numbers = [12, 34, 23, 88, 1, 65]
fruits = ["apple", "pear", "orange", "grapes", "mango"]
fruits.extend(numbers)
print(fruits)
```

I mean, if the logic is the following that at first one function works and then the second, then why in the first one it just works?

I hope I could explain it.

Thanks beforehand,

Lilith

Comment: Because ```replace``` returns the replaced string, while ```extend``` adds the specified list elements to the end of the current list without returning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python strings are *immutable* objects, which means that methods that are performed on them return new strings.

lists on the other hand are mutable, which means you can change them: add items to the list, change specific items in the list etc. These kind of changes are done in place: the same list is changed.

Usually, methods that are done in place do not have a return value. `fruits.extend(numbers)` has no return value because it changes `fruits` in place.

If you need to use `fruits` afterwards your solution of splitting it into two lines is good. If not, you can create a new list and print it as follows:

```py
numbers = [12, 34, 23, 88, 1, 65]
fruits = ["apple", "pear", "orange", "grapes", "mango"]
print(fruits + numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

`.extend(...)` returns `None`. Any method which mutates object in-place returns `None`.

`.replace(...)` returns a new string with replaced values.

But you can try this one-liner.

```
print(fruits.extend(numbers) or fruits)
#['apple', 'pear', 'orange', 'grapes', 'mango', 12, 34, 23, 88, 1, 65]
```

[Docs say :](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>fruits.extend(numbers)
None
```

This will change the fruits
But the new value does not return

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you think it is doing:

```
def extfruits(l1, l2):
    l3 = l1 + l2
    return l3
print(extfruits(fruits, numbers))
```

When in reality, it is printing the Method, which is just changing the value of fruits in place. So, you get None.